# Обновление поля при использовании useFieldArray

Tags: javascript, react-hook-form

Я использую useFieldArray в реакт приложении, чтобы работать динамически с несколькими полями, у меня есть чекбокс, это значение chain, есть textfield это значение clone_name, из, если нужно удалить item я использую remove(index) и это работает, но если мне нужно обновить item до дефолтного значение, то update не работает, я пробовал вместо index указывать 0, но разницы нет, поле не очищается, где-то писали про form.setValue, но зачем тогда здесь метод update? Мне кажется я все делают правильно и в ветвь с else я тоже попадаю 100%, но обновление не происходит

```
 const { control } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
          clones: [{ clone_name: '', chain: 'vl' }],
        },
      });
      const { fields, append, remove, update } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: 'clones',
      });
    
      const handleDeleteClone = index => {
        if (fields.length !== 1) {
          remove(index);
        } else {
          update(index, { clone_name: '', chain: 'vh' });
        }
      };
```